# Background image stopped loading altogether

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I'm using an CDN to use bootstrap in a page I'm building for school, and I added code to load a background image and stretch it across the page. Now the reason this is weird is it just stopped working. It used to load the image no problem, but now it doesn't. When I inspect the page with developer view on chrome and select "Sources" tab, it doesn't even show the image in there. It's on the same directory level as my index.html. The weird thing is, this used to load. It would load, resizing the window looked great, then suddenly it stopped loading the background. I've tried pointing to a different image for it, hard reloading and clearing the cache in developer mode. no dice. No backgrounds are loaded anymore.

```
<style> 
        body {
          background: url('bkgrnd3.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Grainy Travel: Plan Your Escape with 100% Humans! </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        .fakeimg {
        height: 200px;
        background: #aaa;
        }
        </style>
        
        <style> <!--custom style for background images!-->
            body {
   background: url('https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
 }
        </style>
        
        <script>
            var travelImages = ["photos/DenmarkCopenhagen.jpg","photos/EiffeltopParis.jpg","photos/GoldenGateBridge.jpg"]
            var descs = ["Visit a City With Fish!", "Go to the Top of the Eifel Top!", "Check out a Red Bridge Across the Water!"];
            
            var urls = ["https://www.visitcopenhagen.com/", "https://www.toureiffel.paris/en", "https://www.goldengate.org/"]
            function displayImage(index)
            {
                var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
                img.src = travelImages[index];
            }
            
            function openWindow(url)
            {
                var win = open(url, "", "height=200,width=300,top=100,left=100,menubar=no");
                var timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    win.close();
                    }, 3000);
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            .navbar-custom {
            background-color: #20c997;
            }
        </style>        

    </head>
    <body>
    <!--New Bootstrapped Navbar!-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-custom navbar-light sticky-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="Home.png" alt="logo" style="width:30px;">Home</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contacts.html">Agent Information</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="register.html">Customer Registration</a>
          </li>    
        </ul>
      </div>  
    </nav>

        <div class="jumbotron text-center" style="margin-bottom:0 ">
            <h1>Welcome to Grainy Travel</h1>
        </div>
        <article>
                <!--These containers make a table from arrays of images, descriptions and links. Onclicks open links, onmouseovers display an image below the table!-->
                <div class="container"><table class="table table-dark">
                
                    <script>
                        for(var i=0; i < descs.length; i++)
                        {
                            document.write("<tr>");
                            var myString = "<td class=\"col-sm-6\"><img src='" + travelImages[i] + "' onclick='openWindow(\"" + urls[i] + "\")' /></td><td class=\"col-sm-6\">" + descs[i] + "</td>";
                            console.log(myString);
                            document.write(myString);
                            document.write("</tr>");
                        }
                    </script>
                </table></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <table class="table table-dark">
                    
                        <script>
                            for(var i=0; i < descs.length; i++)
                            {
                                document.write("<tr>");
                                var myString = "<td class=\"col-sm-6\" onmouseover='displayImage(" + i + "); '>" + descs[i] + "</td>";
                                console.log(myString);
                                document.write(myString);
                            }
                        </script>
                        <td class="col-sm-6" ><img id="myImage"/>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                </div>
                    
                
        </article>
    <div class="footer">
            Copyright 2021 &copy;
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have a .js file in your project, there could be something possibly breaking in the file. I tried to use the same code you have pasted above and it works fine for me. Although, I faced an issue of the same sort once where my files suddenly stopped showing up in my browser Sources and it was happening due to a code breaking in my corresponding .js file.

Comment: So the only js files in the html are externally delivered via CDN. There's one for bootstrap,  jquery and popper. But if I run without any of these I'll get a notice saying that bootstrap requires jquery in developer view.

Comment: Yeah. You cannot run it without the bootstrap and jquery imports. Can you inspect your element and check what is present on the DOM? If your background image is not appended to the DOM at all, there could be some issue with the order in which you are importing. Maybe bootstrap is not correctly imported. But this again leaves the question, how was it working before? I mean I believe nothing can happen to code all of a sudden. Maybe try to look back at even a single line you changed before it stopped working.

Comment: So if i inspect the body in the DOM, it doesn't seem to receive any parameters from my style/body code snippet above. It's getting two attributes in it's body tag, but none of the changes in the above code seem to be represented in the body attribute in DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone else is following this, it's because I had two sets of  blocks. For whatever reason, when the interpreter gets to the second style block (the one with only navbar customizations) it stops applying anything from the first. So moving the body class edits to the second style block fixed my error. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think lies in the Path of the image. In the jsfiddle below, I have put the full path to an image source from the net for this example. You may try to put the full path in the `css` in the statement `background: url('bkgrnd3.jpg')` for the image `bkgrnd3.jpg`. As you also said the `Source` does not show the image.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: Hey Raky, so I have the background image and everything on the same directory level. Even if I put the code in like you have it, to point it to an image on the web the background image does not get loaded.

Comment: please share your `html` and `js`, if any.

Comment: Added to the original post the full html. the only JS/CSS used are the ones to load in bootstrap and it's required JS (jquery and popper)

Comment: Amended the Snippet for you. It will now work.

Comment: Still doesn't work, actually. I don't know what I broke but I broke something good when I was making other changes, I guess I can build it up from the ground up again as it's not exactly complex.

Answer (score 0):

Change the path of image or try another image
it would help you

Comment: I've pointed it to other images, and even tried pointing it to url web links (like @Raky answer above) and even those won't load.